# Deleted github branch. but rails generated controllers remained in Master?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, github, devise

I am kinda new to programming. I might have not typed the right keyword but I couldn't find anything that would answer this questions. Also GitHub tutorials didn't cover this (as far as I saw).

So installed rails Device gem and everything was working nicely. branched out to  user-sign-up-mailer. I decided to experiment with Device controllers. so I $ rails generate devise:controllers confirmations.

I did stuff there and totally messed my app up. anyway I decided to delete the branch. I checkouted out to master and deleted branch with $ git branch -D user-sign-up-mailer

to my surprise the controllers I generated in branch are in my master. now I feel like I have to reverse that.. but my question is what did do wrong? why did these controllers come to master from? here is the flow from the terminal

so how to i reverse that and Destroy only device controllers?

```
Mac (user-sign-up-mailer) $ rails generate devise:controllers confirmations
Running via Spring preloader in process 19574
      create  app/controllers/confirmations/confirmations_controller.rb
      create  app/controllers/confirmations/passwords_controller.rb
      create  app/controllers/confirmations/registrations_controller.rb
      create  app/controllers/confirmations/sessions_controller.rb
      create  app/controllers/confirmations/unlocks_controller.rb
      create  app/controllers/confirmations/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb
```

---

Some setup you must do manually if you haven't yet:

Ensure you have overridden routes for generated controllers in your routes.rb.
  For example:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    sessions: 'users/sessions'
  }
end
```

---

```
Mac (user-sign-up-mailer) $ git branch -D user-sign-up-mailer
error: Cannot delete the branch 'user-sign-up-mailer' which you are currently on.
Mac (user-sign-up-mailer) $ git checkout master
M   app/models/user.rb
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Mac (master) $ git branch -D user-sign-up-mailer
Deleted branch user-sign-up-mailer (was bdd7590).
Mac (master) $ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   app/models/user.rb

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    app/controllers/confirmations/

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
Mac (master) $
```

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it you never added or committed the files to your branch. Which means git doesn't know about them. That is why they are still on your `master` branch.

You should be fine to delete any of the files listed as untracked, and then you can do a `$ git reset --hard` to remove any of the changes since you last committed your changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can destroy anything you generate by replacing 'generate' with 'destroy' like so:

```
rails destroy devise:controllers confirmations
```

Also, this [site](http://rogerdudler.github.io/git-guide/) helped me a lot when getting started with Git. When switching back to the master branch after you merge changes, be sure to do a hard reset (replace local changes).